# json format with new line separating each row

Tags: r, json

I took mtcars and added fields year, month and day:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(year = "2020", month = "03", day = "05")
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb year month day
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2020    03  05
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2020    03  05
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2020    03  05
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2020    03  05
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2020    03  05
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 2020    03  05
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 2020    03  05
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 2020    03  05
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 2020    03  05
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 2020    03  05
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 2020    03  05
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 2020    03  05
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 2020    03  05
```

I need to get this into json per the following example:

```
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":16,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":22,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":35,"wt":2,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":258,"hp":110,"drat":8,"wt":3,"qsec":19,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":18,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":18,"cyl":6,"disp":225,"hp":105,"drat":2,"wt":3,"qsec":20,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":14,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":245,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":15,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":24,"cyl":4,"disp":146,"hp":62,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":20,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":4,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":22,"cyl":4,"disp":140,"hp":95,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":22,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":4,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":19,"cyl":6,"disp":167,"hp":123,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":17,"cyl":6,"disp":167,"hp":123,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":4,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":16,"cyl":8,"disp":275,"hp":180,"drat":3,"wt":4,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":3,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":17,"cyl":8,"disp":275,"hp":180,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":3,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":15,"cyl":8,"disp":275,"hp":180,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":18,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":3,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":10,"cyl":8,"disp":472,"hp":205,"drat":2,"wt":5,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":10,"cyl":8,"disp":460,"hp":215,"drat":3,"wt":5,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":14,"cyl":8,"disp":440,"hp":230,"drat":3,"wt":5,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":32,"cyl":4,"disp":78,"hp":66,"drat":4,"wt":2,"qsec":19,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":30,"cyl":4,"disp":75,"hp":52,"drat":4,"wt":1,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":33,"cyl":4,"disp":71,"hp":65,"drat":4,"wt":1,"qsec":19,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":4,"disp":120,"hp":97,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":20,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":15,"cyl":8,"disp":318,"hp":150,"drat":2,"wt":3,"qsec":16,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":15,"cyl":8,"disp":304,"hp":150,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":13,"cyl":8,"disp":350,"hp":245,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":15,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":19,"cyl":8,"disp":400,"hp":175,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":17,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":27,"cyl":4,"disp":79,"hp":66,"drat":4,"wt":1,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":26,"cyl":4,"disp":120,"hp":91,"drat":4,"wt":2,"qsec":16,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":5,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":30,"cyl":4,"disp":95,"hp":113,"drat":3,"wt":1,"qsec":16,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":5,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":15,"cyl":8,"disp":351,"hp":264,"drat":4,"wt":3,"qsec":14,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":5,"carb":4,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":19,"cyl":6,"disp":145,"hp":175,"drat":3,"wt":2,"qsec":15,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":5,"carb":6,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":15,"cyl":8,"disp":301,"hp":335,"drat":3,"wt":3,"qsec":14,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":5,"carb":8,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
{"mpg":21,"cyl":4,"disp":121,"hp":109,"drat":4,"wt":2,"qsec":18,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":2,"year":"2020","month":"03","day":"05"}
```

Notice how each new row is on it's own line? Please disregard and ignore the fact that the numbers in my desired output are whole integers, that's a separate thing. I'm interested in the structure of the json.

I tried this:

```
mtcars_json <- jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars %>% mutate(year = "2020", month = "03", day = "05"))
write_json(mtcars_json, "mtcars.json")
```

I then exported that file and opened it in sublime, it looks like this:

```
["[{\"mpg\":21,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":160,\"hp\":110,\"drat\":3.9,\"wt\":2.62,\"qsec\":16.46,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":21,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":160,\"hp\":110,\"drat\":3.9,\"wt\":2.875,\"qsec\":17.02,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":22.8,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":108,\"hp\":93,\"drat\":3.85,\"wt\":2.32,\"qsec\":18.61,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":21.4,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":258,\"hp\":110,\"drat\":3.08,\"wt\":3.215,\"qsec\":19.44,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":18.7,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":360,\"hp\":175,\"drat\":3.15,\"wt\":3.44,\"qsec\":17.02,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":18.1,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":225,\"hp\":105,\"drat\":2.76,\"wt\":3.46,\"qsec\":20.22,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":14.3,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":360,\"hp\":245,\"drat\":3.21,\"wt\":3.57,\"qsec\":15.84,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":24.4,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":146.7,\"hp\":62,\"drat\":3.69,\"wt\":3.19,\"qsec\":20,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":22.8,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":140.8,\"hp\":95,\"drat\":3.92,\"wt\":3.15,\"qsec\":22.9,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":19.2,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":167.6,\"hp\":123,\"drat\":3.92,\"wt\":3.44,\"qsec\":18.3,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":17.8,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":167.6,\"hp\":123,\"drat\":3.92,\"wt\":3.44,\"qsec\":18.9,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":16.4,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":275.8,\"hp\":180,\"drat\":3.07,\"wt\":4.07,\"qsec\":17.4,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":3,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":17.3,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":275.8,\"hp\":180,\"drat\":3.07,\"wt\":3.73,\"qsec\":17.6,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":3,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":15.2,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":275.8,\"hp\":180,\"drat\":3.07,\"wt\":3.78,\"qsec\":18,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":3,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":10.4,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":472,\"hp\":205,\"drat\":2.93,\"wt\":5.25,\"qsec\":17.98,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":10.4,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":460,\"hp\":215,\"drat\":3,\"wt\":5.424,\"qsec\":17.82,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":14.7,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":440,\"hp\":230,\"drat\":3.23,\"wt\":5.345,\"qsec\":17.42,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":32.4,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":78.7,\"hp\":66,\"drat\":4.08,\"wt\":2.2,\"qsec\":19.47,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":30.4,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":75.7,\"hp\":52,\"drat\":4.93,\"wt\":1.615,\"qsec\":18.52,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":33.9,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":71.1,\"hp\":65,\"drat\":4.22,\"wt\":1.835,\"qsec\":19.9,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":21.5,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":120.1,\"hp\":97,\"drat\":3.7,\"wt\":2.465,\"qsec\":20.01,\"vs\":1,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":15.5,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":318,\"hp\":150,\"drat\":2.76,\"wt\":3.52,\"qsec\":16.87,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":15.2,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":304,\"hp\":150,\"drat\":3.15,\"wt\":3.435,\"qsec\":17.3,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":13.3,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":350,\"hp\":245,\"drat\":3.73,\"wt\":3.84,\"qsec\":15.41,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":19.2,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":400,\"hp\":175,\"drat\":3.08,\"wt\":3.845,\"qsec\":17.05,\"vs\":0,\"am\":0,\"gear\":3,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":27.3,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":79,\"hp\":66,\"drat\":4.08,\"wt\":1.935,\"qsec\":18.9,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":1,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":26,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":120.3,\"hp\":91,\"drat\":4.43,\"wt\":2.14,\"qsec\":16.7,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":5,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":30.4,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":95.1,\"hp\":113,\"drat\":3.77,\"wt\":1.513,\"qsec\":16.9,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":5,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":15.8,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":351,\"hp\":264,\"drat\":4.22,\"wt\":3.17,\"qsec\":14.5,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":5,\"carb\":4,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":19.7,\"cyl\":6,\"disp\":145,\"hp\":175,\"drat\":3.62,\"wt\":2.77,\"qsec\":15.5,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":5,\"carb\":6,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":15,\"cyl\":8,\"disp\":301,\"hp\":335,\"drat\":3.54,\"wt\":3.57,\"qsec\":14.6,\"vs\":0,\"am\":1,\"gear\":5,\"carb\":8,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"},{\"mpg\":21.4,\"cyl\":4,\"disp\":121,\"hp\":109,\"drat\":4.11,\"wt\":2.78,\"qsec\":18.6,\"vs\":1,\"am\":1,\"gear\":4,\"carb\":2,\"year\":\"2020\",\"month\":\"03\",\"day\":\"05\"}]"]
```

How can I create a json object in my desired format, with each row on a new line?

Comment: Actually you also seem to want `ndjson` style output rather than proper json output. You can do `con = file("mtcars.json"); stream_out(mtcars %>% mutate(year = "2020", month = "03", day = "05"), con)`  to get something more like that.

Comment: Yes! This looks exactly like what I need. Interested in what's happening here though if you want to make it an answer? Why did we create a con?

Comment: Actually, nm now that I'm thinking about it! I'll delete my comment. Cheers!